# Changed an action in Zabbix, notifications still get sent to old e-mail

Tags: zabbix, notification

I'm using (and am new to) Zabbix 3.0 on CentOS 7. I successfully created an action that sends e-mail to one user. When a condition (e.g. a filesystem more than 80% full) happens, an e-mail gets sent to that user. But now I want the e-mail to go to two users, not just one.

I tried that in two ways. First, I created a "Notifications Receiver" group in Zabbix, set that group's read permisssion to all entities, then made the first user a member of that group. That was my initial setup, with only user 1 being a member. That worked. But when I include the second user in that group, Zabbix ignores me and new notifications still get sent only to the first user.

I edited the action so, instead of that group, notifications are sent to the two users individually:

[image: Zabbix action definition]

But Zabbix ignores me. Everything STILL gets sent only to the one user, the first one. It doesn't even try. This screeenshot for the dashboard shows it only sends e-mail to the first user:

[image: Zabbix dashboard]

Soon after that, the status of the status changed to "Sent" and one e-mail arrived. But it didn't even try to send to the second user even though its media is set correctly, just like the first one:

[image: Zabbix user's Media tab]

I'm at the end of my rope. I'm probably misssing something stupidly obvious.

Answer (score 1):

User media does not seem to be set up the same way. The dashboard screenshot shows the trigger at the "Warning" severity, but the user media only includes "Average", "High" and "Disaster" - notice how "W" is greyed out in "NIWAHD".

Answer (score 0):

There were  two things. One is what @Richlv replied above; another is that Zabbix doesn't seem to be reloading its configuration correctly. I had to go to the server prompt and do this:

```
zabbix_server -R config_cache_reload
```

Comment: That seems unlikely - unless you modified some data that goes in the configuration cache and then retried your test in 60 seconds. By default, the config cache is reloaded every 60 seconds.